# Angular 4 - How to run animation from within Directive?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I have a pending issue on the repo [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15294), but I figured it would be useful to ask it here anyway.

I want to trigger an animation from within a Directive programmatically. When using `Renderer.animate`, I get:

```
Renderer.animate is no longer supported!
```

When using `Renderer.invokeElementMethod`, I get:

```
Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Based on the comments in the referenced issues, it looks like you are supposed to either implement your own renderer or just use `ElementRef.nativeElement`. I would do the latter, depending on the target environment. BTW: +1 for tagging this with JavaScript <3

Comment: Thanks, I see. I just find it odd that there seems to be a complete animation engine under `@angular/animations`, but I'm not able to leverage it appearantly. I'll keep looking for a proper solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changes are coming to Angular! See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15294) in the official Angular repo.

**TL;DR**

> What's really good: With the first beta of angular 4.1 (which comes out as the follow-up release to this weeks 4.0.0) you can do the following:

```
class MyCmp {


constructor(private _builder: AnimationBuilder) {
   }
   myMethod() {
      const animation = this._builder.build([
        style(...),
        animate(...),
        group([
          animate(...)
          animate(...)
          animate(...)
        ])
      ]);
      const player = animation.create(someElement);
      player.play();
   }
}
```